# YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query returns 403 Forbidden in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have used the same script to pull the View metric for specific videos and put it into a spreadsheet for more than a year successfully. Now, all of a sudden the script throws me a forbidden error on the **YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query** line.

I created a blank Apps Script project with the following code to test the issue:

```
function myFunction() {
  var report = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query('channel==MY_CHANNEL_ID','2015-01-01','2015-12-31','views', {filters: 'video==MY_VIDEO_ID'});
  Logger.log(report);
}
```

It throws the same error.

The **Advanced Google services** are switched on and also enabled in the **Developers Console**.

The strange thing is that when I try the same query in the **Developers Console API Explorer**, it works fine.

So to me it seems like Google Apps Script can not identify properly the required scopes to run the script. In fact, I only have the **youtube.readonly** scope in the test project, while the API Explorer also asked for **youtube, yt-analytics-monetry.readonly,yt-analytics.readonly.**

[Test project identified scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkDjk.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Google Apps Script didn't request the required scopes. This has been fixed. If you re-run your script it should work.